# How to parse @import URLs using php dom or regex?

Tags: php, regex, dom, domdocument

Given html such as:

```
<!-- main layout and navbar stylesheets -->
<style type="text/css" media="all and (min-width:481px)">
  @import url("/styles/main.css?v=11") screen, projection;
  @import url("/styles/navbar.css?v=11") screen, projection;
</style>
```

How to get @import URLs out of that chunk of html using php dom or regex ?

*As for what I tried*, here is what I did but it doesn't do it:

```
preg_match("/(url\([\'\"]?)([^\"\'\)]+)([\"\']?\))/", $html, $matches);
```

Comment: That edit wasn't necessary considering you already posted what you tried before anybody could even ask. Lighten up.

Comment: @BoltClock: Agreed posted to account for just-in-case scenarios :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must use DOM**. But **whether to use RegEx its upto you**. Parse the content of style using dom.

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($html);
   $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("style");
   for($i=0;$i<$nodes->length;$i++){
       $style = $nodes->item($i)->textContent;
       // parse import rules on $style here. 
       // read bellow.
   }
```

After that either you use some sort of css parser written in PHP (e.g. [PHP-CSS-Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) ) or apply regex.

A regex like following (escape according to your quote) will parse it well.

```
!@import\s+url\((['"])(.+?)\\1\)!
```

See [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0EgepZ).

Comment: regexp does not match `@import 'file.css';` which is also valid - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import#Examples I recommend regexp by `J. Doe`

Comment: Thats the problem of regex. Content changes and you need to update your regex. :(

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it:

```
<?php
$html = 
'
<!-- main layout and navbar stylesheets -->
<style type="text/css" media="all and (min-width:481px)">
  @import url("/styles/main.css?v=11") screen, projection;
  @import url("/styles/navbar.css?v=11") screen, projection;
</style>
';

if(preg_match_all('/url\(\"([^)]+)\"\)/', $html, $matches)){
  foreach($matches[1] as $url){
      print $url . "<br />";
  }
}else{
  print "No matches";
}

?>
```

**phpfiddle link**: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/w69-ecy

Hope it helps.

Comment: -1. **It'll also parse Non-style tag `@import` text**. Like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BkMIxS). Thats why you should always refrain from using RegEx to parse HTML

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code using php regexp :)

Including a working fiddle also: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yc5-61s

```
<?php    
$inputString = '<!-- main layout and navbar stylesheets -->
<style>url1</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all and (min-width:481px)">
  @import url("/styles/main.css?v=11") screen, projection;
  @import url("/styles/navbar.css?v=11") screen, projection; url
  @import url("http://www.jirilmon/style.css?v=99") screen, projection; url
</style>';


if(preg_match_all('/(@import) (url)\(([^>]*?)\)/',$inputString, $matches)){
  print_r($matches[3]);
}else{
  print "No matches";
}
?>
```

Comment: shilplu, @import rule Imports an external style sheet. So if you found this rule in your html, then your intension was to include css. I dont think people use this rule for any other purpose in html !

Comment: just use the source of this page and apply your regex. You'll get additional 7 rules.

Comment: The source of this page contain some unwanted '@import' text. but no Urls associated with them !

Answer (score 1):

try this one
https://regex101.com/r/QrQxBN/1

working with

```
@import "font-awesome.min.css";
@import "simple-line-icons.css";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700,400);
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ggg');
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ggg");
```

regex

```
preg_match_all ("/@import[ ]*['\"]{0,}(url\()*['\"]*([^;'\"\)]*)['\"\)]*/ui", $csscontent, $urlscss2);
var_dump($cssFile);
var_dump($urlscss2);
```

Comment: `['\"]{0,}` can be changed to `['\"]*` and `(url\()` to `(?:url\()` ... we do not need submatch string "url(" so searched URL will be in $match[1] not $match[2]

Answer (score 0):

Excellent solutions, however is not wider enough, I had to modify it to make it wider and grab different formats of the @import.

```
/@import (url\(\"?)?(url\()?(\")?(.*?)(?(1)\")+(?(2)\))+(?(3)\")/ig
```

With this regex, you can grab this too:

```
@import url(comments.css);
@import "/style/main.css"
@import url("style-1024.css")
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/uC4sH2/1